# How many process can we find to prove Cayley-Hamilton theorem for $2 \times 2$ matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was wandering to think that is there any easy way to prove Cayley-Hamilton theorem for $A \in M(2, \Bbb R)$, i.e it satisfies its characteristic polynomial.

I was trying to think in this way that

i) If $A$ has two distinct real eigenvalues (say) $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ then $A$ is similar to 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 & 0  \\
        0 & \lambda_2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

ii) If $A$ has two distinct purely imaginary eigenvalues $a \pm ib$ then $A$ is similar to $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b  \\
        -b & a \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

iii) If $A$ has one real eigenvalue (say)$\lambda$ of multiplicity two then $A$ is similar to 
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 0  \\
        0 & \lambda \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ or $$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda & 0  \\
        1 & \lambda \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ 
 Now characteristic polynomial of similar matrices are same but this does not help me anything next...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that:
$$
\det (A)=\det
\begin{bmatrix}
a-\lambda&b\\
c&d-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}= \lambda^2- (a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=  \lambda^2- tr (A)\lambda+det (A)$$

so the caharacteristic equation is $\lambda^2- tr (A)\lambda+det (A)I=0$

Now we can easely werify that $A^2- tr (A)A+det (A)=0$ : see my answer to:  [Show that a matrix $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ satisfies $A^2-(a+d)A+(ad-bc)I=O$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494369/show-that-a-matrix-a-pmatrixab-cd-satisfies-a2-adaad-bci-o/1494390#1494390).