# " Let $A$ be a symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix with the property $A^{-1} = A$. Find all possible trace values ​of $\operatorname{tr}A$"

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, trace, symmetric-matrices

I need some help solving this.
I have tried:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\
    \end{bmatrix}
=\frac{1}{\operatorname{det}A}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    d & -b  \\
    -c & a  \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
I ended up with $$a=\frac{d}{\operatorname{det}A},$$
and
$$d=\frac{a}{\operatorname{det}A}.$$
Then
$$\operatorname{tr}(A)=a+d=\frac{a+d}{\operatorname{det}A},$$
but I don't really think it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is easier if you think about it in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$.  Note that if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, we have $A^{-1}x = Ax$. What does this tell you about that eigenvalue?

Comment: Maybe $A^{-1}$ =λ and A=λ ?

Comment: What does $A^{-1} = \lambda$ mean?  Do you mean that the $2 \times 2$ matrix $A^{-1}$ is equal to the number $\lambda$?

Comment: Look closely at the definition of an eigenvalue/eigenvector, and maybe you'll figure it out from there.

Comment: Both of the $A^{-1}$ and A will have the same eigenvalues right?

Comment: Of course, $A^{-1} = A$ means that $A^{-1}$ and $A$ will have the same eigenvalues.  However, what is generally the relationship between the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ and the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: Another point worth considering: if you multiply both sides of $A^{-1} = A$ by $A$, you see that $A^2 = I$.  How do the eigenvalues of $A^2$ compare to the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: I cant really figure out the connection between the eigenvalues except they are the same.

Comment: @johnienna if $Ax = \lambda x$, what can we say about $A(Ax))$?  What do you think we could say about $A^{-1}(x)$?

Comment: Fact: Sum of eigenvalues is trace, product of eigenvalues is determinant

Answer (score 1):

By the Cayley–Hamilton theorem or [direct verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494369/show-that-a-matrix-a-pmatrixab-cd-satisfies-a2-adaad-bci-o), we have $A^{2}-\operatorname {tr}(A)A+\det(A)I=0$.

From $A^2=I$, we get $\operatorname {tr}(A)A=(\det(A)+1)I$.

Taking traces on both sides, we get $\operatorname {tr}(A)^2=2(\det(A)+1)$.

From $A^2=I$, we also get $\det(A)^2=1$ and so $\det(A)=\pm1$.

If $\det(A)=1$, then $\operatorname {tr}(A)^2=4$ and so $\operatorname {tr}(A)=\pm 2$.

If $\det(A)=-1$, then $\operatorname {tr}(A)^2=0$ and so $\operatorname {tr}(A)=0$.

These three possibilities occur for the matrices below:
$$
\operatorname {tr}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = 2
\qquad
\operatorname {tr}\begin{pmatrix}-1&\hphantom-0\\\hphantom-0&-1\end{pmatrix} = -2
\qquad
\operatorname {tr}\begin{pmatrix}1&\hphantom-0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix} = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have $A^{-1} = A \implies A^2 = I$. So we just calculate that for the matrix you have $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 + bc & (a+d)\cdot b \\ (a+d)\cdot c & bc + d^2 \end{pmatrix}$$

Therefore, you get $(a+d)\cdot b = (a+d)\cdot c = 0$.

Case 1: $a+d = 0$, we're done.

Case 2: Let's assume $b$ or $c$ are $0$ then $a^2 = d^2 = 1 \implies a^2 - d^2 = 0 \implies a = \pm d$.

If $a = -d \implies a+d = 0$

If $a = d$, then $A = aI$, and $A^2 = I \implies a = \pm 1 \implies A = \pm I$

Therefore, for $A^2 = I$, we have $\text{tr} A = 0, 2 , -2$

---

**Continuing from your chain of thought**

In your calculations, you obtained the following,

$$a+d = \frac{a+d}{\det A}$$
Now, as we know if $A^2 = I$, then $\det A = \pm1$.

Therefore, for $\det A = -1$. You get $$a+d = -(a+d) \implies \text{tr} A = 0$$

For $\det A = 1$, you get $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} d & -b\\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$$

$\implies b = c = 0, a = d$. Therefore $A = aI$, and $\text{tr} A = 2a$
$$A^2 = I \implies (aI)^2 = I \implies a^2 = 1 \implies a = \pm 1$$

Hence, $\text{tr} A = \pm 2$

**Comment:** For a more 'clean' answer, please refer to Omnomnomnom's answer/response. I provided an elementary answer to demonstrate one exists, but the better and faster way, in my opinion, is still using eigenvalues.

Comment: And what about the identity matrix $A=I=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Since we chose an arbitrary matrix, I'm just discounting that possibility. Since for $I$, this fact is already true

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "I discounted this possibility"??? Is $A=I$ a symmetric $2\times2$ matrix satisfying $A^{-1}=A$ or not?

Comment: I edited by answer accordingly

Comment: Apologies, I realised my folly

Comment: I understood your answer but i dont really get Omnomnomnom's answer,cant think of a way eigenvalues can help me

Comment: Well, the idea is basically this. Since you have A as a $2 \times 2$ matrix, you will have 2 eigenvalues. And it is a known fact that the sum of these eigenvalues is precisely the trace of $A$. And also another fact that for any invertible matrix (which $A$ is), if it's eigenvalue is, say, $\lambda$. The eigenvalue of it's inverse is $1/\lambda$. But in your case, $A = A^{-1} \implies \lambda = 1/\lambda \implies \lambda = \pm 1$. Then you get the trace as, taking all possibilities, $1 - 1, 1+1, -1-1 = 0, 2, -2$

Comment: Another hint given by @Omnomnomnom is using the fact $A^2 = I$. Another fact, if the eigenvalue of a matrix is, say, $\lambda$, the eigenvalue of a square is $\lambda^2$. And the eigenvalue of $I$ is $1$. Therefore $\lambda^2 = 1$, and rest follows.

Comment: Proof of the facts above: 1. $Ax = \lambda x \implies x = A^{-1} \lambda x \implies A^{-1}x = (1/\lambda)x$

$Ax = \lambda x \implies A(Ax) = A(\lambda x) \implies A^2x = \lambda (Ax) \implies A^2 x = \lambda^2 x$

Comment: To see why trace is sum of eigenvalues, just look at the characteristic polynomial and you'll get your answer, and also the fact that the product of eigenvalues is the determinant

Comment: How did you get from here : λ(Ax) to here? λ^2 x

Comment: Remember, we originally have $Ax = \lambda x$, right? That's what we started with. So $\lambda (Ax) = \lambda \cdot \lambda x = \lambda^2 x$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76562/discussion-between-johnienna-and-junkquill).